# Understanding RSSI inacurracy on RaspberryPi

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, rssi

I'm experimenting with iBeacon tracking on a RaspberryPi and have a problem with the accuracy of the retrieved RSSI. I use the following hardware:
- RaspberryPi (newest version)
- IOGear Bluetooth 4.0 USB Micro Adapter
- BEACONinside Beacon (Model: B0001-A)

I tested iBeacon advertisment scanning using the official BEACONinside Android app and the retrieved RSSI is intuitively very accurate. Then I tested advertisment scanning using aforementioned hardware on a RaspberryPi and the retrieved RSSI is very inaccurate. Does anybody have an idea what the reason for this inacurracy could be? Possible origins for the problem are in my optinion the Bluetooth adpater, which differs from the one in my Android phone. Another reason could be the library for Bluetooth scanning (on the RaspberryPi, I'm using bluez). What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by inaccurate?  Can you post some data?  Every receiving device has a different antenna which will get different RSSI values.

Answer (score 0):

RSSI is generally effected by surrounding environments so it should be

averaged for couple of seconds to get accurate value